# How to replace the System class in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, system

A piece of code performs the same logic, but has two different entry points. As a result it must use System.getProperty in the case of one entry point, and this.getProperty in the case of the other entry point. I would ideally like to temporarily and conveniently replace System with this or vice versa in one of the cases so that I do not have to duplicate the logic for the two different entry points.

Comment: @sunrize920 I think the question is forumlated sufficiently in this case. The OP wishes to dynamically switch between `System` static methods and methods of an object based on entry points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `this.getProperty(` call the `System.getProperty(` static method as needed. Create a boolean, `useSystem` as a field of `this`.

Then, define `this.getProperty(` as follows:

```
String this.getProperty(String arg){
    if useSystem return System.getProperty(arg);
    else{
        //your logic for returning a property
    }
}
```

Always call `this.getProperty(` when getting a property. Depending on the entry point, you can set `this.useSystem` to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple if else statement:

```
String property = isEntryPoint ? System.getProperty() : this.getProperty();
```

Supposing that isEntryPoint is a boolean flag that determines which entry point is using.